# How to throw/catch exceptions in a Test::More subtests?

Tags: perl, exception

**Is there a way how to throw exceptions** (aka. `die` and `Carp` family members) **from child subtests and be able to catch them** (aka. `eval` or `lives_ok`) **in the parent subtest in Perl 5.10?**

I want to run a set of tests inside a for loop like this:

```
use Test::More;
use Test::Exception;

for (my $i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {
    subtest("outer $i" => sub {
        lives_ok(sub {
            inner();
        }, "lives_ok");
        done_testing();
    });
    note("Outer code should continue regardless of exceptions in inner().\n");
}
```

And the inner() tests I call can die within a child subtest, e.g.:

```
sub inner {
    subtest("inner" => sub {
        ok(1, 'ok');
        die("EXCEPTION message here");
        note("This code should NOT be reached\n");
        done_testing();
    });
}
```

And when the `inner` subtest dies, I want to be able to continue with the next outer test. However, in the above example the outer test dies as well, `lives_ok` is useless for my problem:

```
        ok 1 - ok
        # Child (inner) exited without calling finalize()
    not ok 1 - inner
    not ok 2 - lives_ok
    1..2
    #   Failed test 'inner'
    #   Failed test 'lives_ok'
    # died: EXCEPTION message here at ...
    # Child (outer 0) exited without calling finalize()
not ok 1 - outer 0
#   Failed test 'outer 0'
# ---------------
# Can't call finalize() with child (inner) active at Test/Builder.pm line 229.
# ---------------
# Tests were run but no plan was declared and done_testing() was not seen.
```

In real life `inner` actually calls many functions that can die, so I am looking for a solution which involves changing only the `outer` loop.

If that is not possible and I will have to `eval` (aka. `lives_ok`) every single statement inside all of my inner subtests that can die, how can I avoid nested testing of whether `lives_ok` passed or not?

```
my $result1;
my $lived1 = lives_ok {$result1 = do_something() or die;} "test1";
if ($lived1) {
    # test2 can only be executed if there was no exception in test1
    my $lived2 = lives_ok {do_something_else} "test2";
    if (...) 
}
```

*EDIT: there can be 100s of TAP output lines per 1 loop, so I do want to use nested subtests*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone suggests a better solution, I am going to refactor a bit and use this kind of workaround - never directly die inside a subtest and call all functions that can die with lives_ok from within the subtest.

Using example from the question:

```
sub inner {
    subtest("inner" => sub {
        ok(1, 'ok');
        $err = "EXCEPTION message here";
        if (not $err) {
            note("This code should NOT be reached\n");
        }
        done_testing();
    });
    confess($err) if $err;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An uncaught exception happening within a subtest (and thus causing the subtest's coderef to end prematurely) is considered an error by Test::More/Test::Builder, so it panics and bails.

In this particular example I'd suggest that there's probably no need for nesting a second level of subtests. `inner` could be rewritten as:

```
sub inner {
#   subtest("inner" => sub {
        ok(1, 'ok');
        die("EXCEPTION message here");
        note("This code should NOT be reached\n");
#       done_testing();
#   });
}
```

... and then your entire test script will run. (And of course the tests fail because of the `lives_ok` tests.)

Comment: of course I DO need to use nested subtests to make sense of the thousands of lines of TAP output,, does the question look like that I don't??

Comment: You can make a sequence of tests *look* a little like subtests by doing things along the lines of `ok(1, "some test"); ok(2, "... and blah"); ok(3, "... and blah");` The dots indent the results quite nicely. [Example](https://github.com/tobyink/p5-type-tiny/blob/master/t/20-unit/Type-Coercion/frozen.t).